# Magento removal of GuruIncsite infection, in database tables

Tags: mysql, magento, malware

Guruincsite malware issue 
infected 2 x magento 1.9 community websites 
went through the standard proceedures as advised on a number of websites such as: 
System > Configuration > Design > Footer > Miscellaneous HTML and find the malicious code. - nothing there 
Users: numerous users created - removed all 
changed .htaccess file just in case

now checked DB with the search phrase: 
function LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1 
at least one of the words  
select all tables  
go. 
this code was found in the following tables: 
catalog_product_flat_1 
 
catalog_product_entity_text 
catalog_product_entity_varchar 
catalogsearch_fulltext 
cms_page 
core_config_data 
core_url_rewrite 
m2epro_ebay_dictionary_marketplace

then click on a table to browse 
do not go into the table but click on edit above where you see code like this: 
    SELECT * FROM `way_radio4`.`catalog_category_flat_store_1` WHERE (CONVERT(`entity_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'

here you will see that the malware has duplicated the functions for its own purposes 
e.g. catalog_product_flat_1 table 
this is the code 
please note: simply trying to remove the code does not work - once you search again it is back again?? no idea why - any ideas?

```
SELECT *  FROM `way_radio4`.`catalog_category_flat_store_1`
WHERE (CONVERT(`entity_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`parent_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`created_at` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`updated_at` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`path` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`position` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`level` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`children_count` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`store_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`name` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`is_active` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`url_key` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`description` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`image` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`meta_title` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`meta_keywords` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`meta_description` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`display_mode` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`landing_page` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`is_anchor` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`all_children` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`path_in_store` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`children` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`url_path` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`custom_design` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`custom_design_from` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`custom_design_to` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`page_layout` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`custom_layout_update` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`available_sort_by` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`default_sort_by` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`include_in_menu` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`custom_use_parent_settings` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`custom_apply_to_products` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%'
OR CONVERT(`filter_price_range` USING utf8) LIKE '%function%') 
OR  (CONVERT(`entity_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`parent_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`created_at` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`updated_at` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`path` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`position` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`level` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`children_count` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`store_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`name` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`is_active` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`url_key` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`description` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`image` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`meta_title` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`meta_keywords` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`meta_description` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`display_mode` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`landing_page` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`is_anchor` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`all_children` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`path_in_store` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`children` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`url_path` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_design` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_design_from` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_design_to` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`page_layout` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_layout_update` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`available_sort_by` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`default_sort_by` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`include_in_menu` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_use_parent_settings` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_apply_to_products` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`filter_price_range` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1)
{XHFER1=XHFER1%')
```

so basically i need to remove the following in each table:

```
OR  (CONVERT(`entity_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`parent_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`created_at` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`updated_at` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`path` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`position` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`level` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`children_count` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`store_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`name` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`is_active` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`url_key` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`description` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`image` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`meta_title` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`meta_keywords` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`meta_description` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`display_mode` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`landing_page` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`is_anchor` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`all_children` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`path_in_store` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`children` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`url_path` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_design` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_design_from` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_design_to` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`page_layout` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_layout_update` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`available_sort_by` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`default_sort_by` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`include_in_menu` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_use_parent_settings` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`custom_apply_to_products` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%' OR CONVERT(`filter_price_range` USING utf8) LIKE '%LCWEHH(XHFER1){XHFER1=XHFER1%')
```

Comment: manually highlight and delete the relevant text - click go - and while in the table it appears to be deleted but then when you do a search to check it is back there.

Comment: If it is coming back, your server is still compromised. Look for compromised credentials allowing the attacker to log in and insert or for scripts that do sql injection into the database.

Comment: Hi - i contacted the company that we get the server from (its a managed service) and they couldn't assist saying we would have to contact magento for a solution.   In the end we restored a back up far enough back prior to the issue, updated all extensions, added security etc.. and all is good  - thanks for comments though